# Binding jQuery ready and ajaxStop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What is the best way to use `ready` and `ajaxStop` together in jQuery? Currently I am using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).bind('ready ajaxStop', function() {
        $('[rel=tooltip], [data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
            html: true
        });     
    });
});
```

To me it seems redundant to use `ready` inside `ready`. It was the only think I could think of without duplicating code. Is there another event I should be calling with `ajaxStop` instead of `ready`? Or is there a better way to initialize my tooltip, along with a few other plugins and custom JS, which needs to be loaded on ready as well as when my page is reloaded via Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this by firing a custom event every time page is reloaded with ajax or otherwise when the page content changes.

Also you don't need to handle ready again. Abstract the tooltip initialization code in another function, call the function directly or trigger the custom event.